# QGIS Processing error with SAGA, "output layer could not be open"

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-processing

QGIS 2.4.0
SAGA GIS 2.0.8

DESCRIPTION:

Error when processing with SAGA. I used the "Shapes to Grid" function. The error given: "Oooops! The following output layers could not be open".

This error seems to be very common, but I can't find any solution that works. I have read various posts, but there is no answer to fix this error that seems to work. I am currently using the latest version of both QGIS and SAGA GIS.

ERROR:

```
Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
Grid:  C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif  
The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected  
This algorithm requires SAGA to be run. A test to check if SAGA is correctly installed and configured in your system has been performed, with the following result:      
SAGA seems to be correctly installed and configured
```

LOG:

```
Algorithm Shapes to grid starting...
grid_gridding "Shapes to Grid" -INPUT "C:/Pieter & Wiesie Burger/BackUP Werk/Overberg Agri/Geografies/Data/Roodebloem/Stroper GPS/2012 Stroop/RB7 - BAR 2012 - 12110600 - filter points.shp" -FIELD "ERTRAG" -MULTIPLE 0 -LINE_TYPE 0 -GRID_TYPE 3 -USER_XMIN 24.53824 -USER_XMAX 14.54312 -USER_YMIN -29.24768 -USER_YMAX -39.24041 -USER_SIZE 10 -USER_GRID "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd"
io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 1 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>saga_cmd grid_gridding "Shapes to Grid" -INPUT "C:/Pieter & Wiesie Burger/BackUP Werk/Overberg Agri/Geografies/Data/Roodebloem/Stroper GPS/2012 Stroop/RB7 - BAR 2012 - 12110600 - filter points.shp" -FIELD "ERTRAG" -MULTIPLE 0 -LINE_TYPE 0 -GRID_TYPE 3 -USER_XMIN 24.53824 -USER_XMAX 14.54312 -USER_YMIN -29.24768 -USER_YMAX -39.24041 -USER_SIZE 10 -USER_GRID "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd"
_____________________________________________
##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

library path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga\modules
library name: grid_gridding
module name : Shapes to Grid
author : O.Conrad (c) 2003
_____________________________________________
go...

Load shapes: C:/Pieter & Wiesie Burger/BackUP Werk/Overberg Agri/Geografies/Data/Roodebloem/Stroper GPS/2012 Stroop/RB7 - BAR 2012 - 12110600 - filter points.shp...

ready
okay

Parameters

Shapes: RB7 - BAR 2012 - 12110600 - filter points
Attribute: ERTRAG
Method for Multiple Values: first
Method for Lines: thin
Preferred Target Grid Type: Floating Point (4 byte)
Target Grid: user defined


**error:** executing module [Shapes to Grid]

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 1 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif"
_____________________________________________
##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
_____________________________________________

library path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps\saga\modules
library name: io_gdal
module name : GDAL: Export Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007
_____________________________________________
go...

Load grid: C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd...

**failed**

**error**: Grid file could not be opened.

**error**: input file [C:\Users\Burger\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d6e5c059ffc247328315ea134947d3da\USERGRID.tif.sgrd]

**error**: empty input list [GRIDS]
Usage: 1 -GRIDS [-FILE ] [-FORMAT ] [-TYPE ]
-GRIDS: Grid(s)
Grid list (input)
-FILE: File
File path
-FORMAT: Format
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Virtual Raster
[1] GeoTIFF
[2] National Imagery Transmission Format
[3] Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
[4] ELAS
[5] In Memory Raster
[6] MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
[7] PCIDSK Database File
[8] ILWIS Raster Map
[9] SGI Image File Format 1.0
[10] Leveller heightfield
[11] Terragen heightfield
[12] ERMapper .ers Labelled
[13] Raster Matrix Format
[14] Idrisi Raster A.1
[15] Intergraph Raster
[16] Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
[17] Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
[18] ENVI .hdr Labelled
[19] ESRI .hdr Labelled
[20] PCI .aux Labelled
[21] Vexcel MFF Raster
[22] Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
[23] VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
[24] Image Data and Analysis
[25] NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
[26] NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
[27] ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
[28] SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
-TYPE: Data Type
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] match input data
[1] 8 bit unsigned integer
[2] 16 bit unsigned integer
[3] 16 bit signed integer
[4] 32 bit unsigned integer
[5] 32 bit signed integer
[6] 32 bit floating point
[7] 64 bit floating point

**error**: executing module [GDAL: Export Raster]

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin>exit
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm Shapes to grid finished
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution! SAGA GIS 2.0.8 installed with QGIS is not the latest version.

> The latest version of SAGA GIS can be obtained from:
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/?source=typ_redirect

Currently, version 2.1.2 is on their website (2014/09/06).

Steps:

1. Download latest SAGA version from link above.
2. Extract ZIP file
3. Copy the folder to C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\apps
4. You can delete the current "saga" folder or just rename it, e.g. to "saga - old"
5. Rename the copied "saga_2.1.2_win32" folder to "saga"

You can run QGIS again and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem that can be caused by the data size and computer environment.

I run a `32 bit` QGIS version on `64 bit` Windows machine.
I need the `32 bit` QGIS for a certain scentific plugin that can not be run in the `64 bit` QGIS. Therefore, I do not uninstall it.

I try to `resample` a 2m tif raster (17017x19063 cells) into 30 m tif raster. 
I also try to `translate` the tif file to asc grid file.
Both effort can not be finished.
I try to re install my `32 bit` QGIS version but still the same.

Later on, I try these methods an these work for me:
1. I crop the 2m tif into smaller area and then re try the `resample` and `translate` processes.
2. I try to install the `64 bit` Qgis version side by side with the `32 bit`, I use the `64 bit` version for `resampling` and `translating` the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 7 years since this questions was posted.
But I ran into this exact same error yesterday.
I am using QGIS 3.22.6 with SAGA 7.8.2 on Windows.

I have been using a couple of SAGA tools in QGIS for a couple of weeks and they worked just fine. However, SAGA tools went missing all of sudden.

After I created a new profile, the SAGA tools came back but they stopped working properly. I reinstalled QGIS, but it did not work.

So I did what PieterB said.
I downloaded saga-7.8.2_x64.zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%207/SAGA%20-%207.8.2/ and replaced the SAGA folder in QGIS with the newly downloaded one.

It worked.

I am sure this bug will be fixed in a couple of days. But in case you run into this error and need a workaround, you can have a try.