# QGIS SAGA "Natural Neighbourhood" gridding error

Tags: qgis, saga

I'm having issues with saving my grid out to file. Every time I try, I get the error " The output layer could was not generated"

C:\Users\Name\Documents\QGIS\Rav.tif

'Check error log for more information'

I tried the option of save to temporary location but same issue and as you would notice,my path does not contain any whitespace...

I'm using QGIS 3.0 and this was the same issue with 2.2.18 Las Palmas version

I checked this question however [QGIS Processing error with SAGA, "output layer could not be open"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112919/qgis-processing-error-with-saga-output-layer-could-not-be-open?rq=1)

**Here's the log**

Processing algorithm…
AlgorithmDialog
Input parameters:
{ 'SHAPES' : 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavSpotH.shp', 'FIELD' : 'ALT', 'SIBSON' : True, 'OUTPUT_EXTENT' : '7.924584,7.933957,5.04092,5.04547 [EPSG:32632]', 'TARGET_USER_SIZE' : 0.0005, 'TARGET_USER_FITS' : 0, 'TARGET_OUT_GRID' : 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavDEM.tif' }

grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavSpotH.shp" -FIELD "ALT" -SIBSON true -TARGET_USER_XMIN 7.924584 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 5.04092 -TARGET_USER_YMIN 7.933957 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 5.04547 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.0005 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavDEM.tif"

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps\saga-ltr

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\qt5\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\WBem;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin>saga_cmd grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavSpotH.shp" -FIELD "ALT" -SIBSON true -TARGET_USER_XMIN 7.924584 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 5.04092 -TARGET_USER_YMIN 7.933957 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 5.04547 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.0005 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavDEM.tif"
Unknown option 'SIBSON'

---

## #####

#### ### ##

#### # ## ## #### #

#### ##### ## #

# ## ##### #

---

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

---

library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: grid_gridding
library : Gridding
tool : Natural Neighbour
author : O.Conrad (c) 2008
processors : 2 [2]

---

Usage: saga_cmd grid_gridding 3 [-SHAPES ] [-FIELD ] [-TARGET_DEFINITION ] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE ] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN ] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX ] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN ] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX ] [-TARGET_USER_FITS ] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE ] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID ] [-METHOD ] [-WEIGHT ]
-SHAPES: Points
Shapes (input)
-FIELD: Attribute
Table field
-TARGET_DEFINITION: Target Grid System
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] user defined
[1] grid or grid system
Default: 0
-TARGET_USER_SIZE: Cellsize
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMIN: Left
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMAX: Right
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMIN: Bottom
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMAX: Top
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_FITS: Fit
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] nodes
[1] cells
Default: 0
-TARGET_TEMPLATE: Target System
Grid (optional input)
-TARGET_OUT_GRID: Target Grid
Grid (output)
-METHOD: Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Linear
[1] Sibson
[2] Non-Sibsonian
Default: 1
-WEIGHT: Minimum Weight
Floating point
Maximum: 0.000000
Default: 0.000000

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin>exit
Execution completed in 20.94 seconds
Results:
{'TARGET_OUT_GRID': 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavDEM.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
C:/Users/HP/Documents/QGIS/Ravine/RavDEM.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Could you add full description of the error log? I cannot reproduce this error (using QGIS 3.2.1), unless intentionally giving it a bad data.

Comment: Have edited the question to include the log

Comment: Thanks! Not sure, but there is a suspicious message `Unknown option 'SIBSON'` which probably corresponds to `-SIBSON true`. Is it possible for you to use QGIS 3.2.1? (There is a problem with 3.2.1... it allows only `.sdat` format as an interim output.)

Comment: I saw that and unchecked it but still didn't work. Yeah I guess I could try updating to QGIS 3.2.1. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in QGIS 3.2 - looks like an upgrade is in order!

Comment: yeah true but I'm not getting the request as that of the tutorial i followed...